# Logstash 6.2.4 crashes when adding an ID to plugin (Expected one of #)

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to add ID field to my Logstash 6.2.4 config. What i want to do is to debug "http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipelines" so i need some names (id is random UUIDs without id field in configs). I found [documentation about plugin id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-id). It works for me like this:

```
input {
    http {
        port => "${HTTP_PORT_FOR_EVENTS:8089}"
        additional_codecs => {"application/json"=>"json"}
        id => "http_events"
        tags => [ "test" ]
    }
}

filter {
    if "test" in [tags]  {
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "headers", "host" ]   
        }
    }
}
```

But it crashes like this:

```
input {
    http {
        port => "${HTTP_PORT_FOR_EVENTS:808}"
        additional_codecs => {"application/json"=>"json"}
        id => "http_events"
        tags => [ "test" ]
    }
}

filter {
    id => "test2"
    if "test" in [tags]  {
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "headers", "host" ]   
        }
    }
}
```

With this error (i guess, there is two erros with shutdown between because of Docker container restart or something):

> Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, { at line 32, column 8 (byte 676) after filter {\r\n    id ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in`compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in`map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in`initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in`execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in `block in converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in `converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in`block in converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in`converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:105:in `block in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:18:in`interval'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:94:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in`block in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
>
> SIGTERM received. Shutting down.
>   Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
>   Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
>   Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
>   Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
>   Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.4"}
>   Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
>   SIGTERM received. Shutting down.
>
> Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
>   Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
>   Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
>   Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
>   Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.4"}
>   Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
>
> Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, { at line 24, column 8 (byte 534) after filter {\n    id ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in`compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in`map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in`initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in`execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in `block in converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in `converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in`block in converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in`converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in`block in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}

Those configs are also break my logstash:

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        id => "test1"
        type => "event"
        exchange => "event"
        exclusive => true
    }
}


input {
    id => "test1"
    rabbitmq {
        type => "event"
        exchange => "event"
        exclusive => true
    }
}
```

Comment: `id => "test2"` is not a valid part of the config.

Comment: If you want to add a field to your event, you have to use the add_field option of a filter plugin (cf [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field)).

Comment: No, i want a name for my plugins so i can find them in metrics (otherwise there are only generated uuids). Here they use is in docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-id and one of the configs works with it, but i don't understand why others don't.

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood what you wanted to do (and didn't know about the id option), sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

ID must be placed in *filter plugin field* (such as grok, mutate or json), not just in filter field:

```
filter {
    if "test" in [tags]  {
        mutate {
            id => "test2"
            remove_field => [ "headers", "host" ]   
        }
    }
}
```

Also not every version of plugins support IP field. Update plugins if necessary:

```
logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-mutate
```